# Rename folder using wildcard windows

Tags: windows-server-2008, wildcard, batch, rename, directory

I've got a piece of software that includes its own backup utility, but it generates folder names with the current date and time appended.  I'd like to write batch script that will remove the date/time part of the folder name

essentially I'd like to rename c:\my folder\backup12345\ to c:\my folder\backup\

I've tried the obvious:

`ren "c:\my folder\backup*" "backup"`

which returns "The syntax of the command is incorrect."

This feels like it should be so simple, but I can't work out why it won't work

Answer (score 3):

Turns out the answer was very simple:

`move "c:\my folder\backup*" "c:\my folder\backup"`